# R Neural Networks - Weights

Tags: r

I have an error message when I use weights in nnet() even though the package documentation says weights.  However, if I use wts it works.  I suppose weight defaults to 1 if I don't enter any value.

Regardless of the wts value that I enter nnet() always return weights = 83 , how does 83 weights get assigned ?.  please look at the output below:

I suppose I don't really understand how these weights are assigned

Any help appreciated. Thank you.

```
attach(iris)

library(caret)
set.seed(3456)
trainIndex <- createDataPartition(iris$Species, p = .8,
                              list = F,
                              times = 1)

irisTrain <- iris[ trainIndex,]
irisTest  <- iris[-trainIndex,]

irispred <- nnet(Species ~ ., data=irisTrain ,weights = 1, size=10)
predicted <- predict(irispred,irisTest,type="class")
```

Error when using weights (package documentations says use weights)

```
irispred <- nnet(Species ~ ., data=irisTrain ,weights = 1, size=10)
Error in model.frame.default(formula = Species ~ ., data = irisTrain,  : 
  variable lengths differ (found for '(weights)')
```

No error if I use wts:

```
irispred <- nnet(Species ~ ., data=irisTrain ,wts = 1, size=10)
# weights:  83
initial  value 148.744330 
iter  10 value 20.508558
iter  20 value 7.683385
iter  30 value 5.719438
iter  40 value 3.831845
iter  50 value 3.524789
iter  60 value 3.461561
iter  70 value 3.352866
iter  80 value 3.061214
iter  90 value 3.049519
iter 100 value 3.001406
final  value 3.001406 
stopped after 100 iterations

irispred$wts
 [1]    0.46982680904   -1.08944343286   -0.85761073123   -2.05356837297   -1.56599897345
 [6]  291.18284632141   31.85356741288   27.37999662827  -97.45738049129  -55.50299935575
[11]   -1.36175718738 .......Up to 83.

> irispred <- nnet(Species ~ ., data=irisTrain ,wts = 28, size=10)
# weights:  83
initial  value 143.546315 
iter  10 value 55.502915
iter  20 value 40.514073
iter  30 value 6.610363
iter  40 value 6.111119
iter  50 value 6.019070
iter  60 value 5.963004
iter  70 value 5.956329
iter  80 value 5.945786
iter  90 value 5.942088
iter 100 value 5.939509
final  value 5.939509 
stopped after 100 iterations
> irispred$wts
 [1]   1.07816704818   1.89161925466   1.36901821472  -0.39336454435  -0.23879356006
 [6]  -0.63780061885  -2.62845406757 ... up to 83
```

Comment: Weights: 83 is the number of rows (weights). Notice that weights should be a vector that equals number of cases (rows).

Comment: The number of rows in the training dataset is 120, not sure why it is 83